# why slide top does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me why slide top does not work ? here is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qEjXj/1934/

```
$(".slidingDiv").toggle("slide", {direction:'top'});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direction attribute is an extension from jQuery UI. Vertical directions are "up" and "down", not top and bottom. You can read about it here:
http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=UI/Effects/Slide&redirect=no

jQuery also comes with this which might be what you're looking for:

```
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
```

Comment: so it should be "up" instead of "top"

Comment: Exactly. But I wouldn't use jQuery UI unless I needed some of the other features.

Comment: why so ? because it is worthless to load the whole Js just for this ?

Comment: Yeah, why load an additional js library if you don't have to? 
Don't get me wrong, there are some good features in there and it's modular so you don't have to load all of it. But if you don't need it, don't bother.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle("slow");
```